# How get users from section table ? laravel

Tags: laravel

The idea is that I have relation between two table's **section** and **user**

the **section_id** exist in users table it relation with **id**  section

**SO** for ex : section_id = 2 > want to bring all users belongs to  id section

My code here use id from url and I don't want to do this I want without id bring all users :

```
public function getAllUsers($id)
{
  $data = User::where('section_id',$id)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to get all the users for a particular **Section** that have the relationship to that section.

Assuming you have the relationship set up correctly on the **Section** model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

I suggest you go about this 'backward' and just pull the users from the **Section** model itself (eager loading allows one query):

```
$section = Section::with('users')->first();
$usersForThisSection = $section->users;
```

Comment: it's return all users here !

Comment: Do all of your users have the same `section_id`?  It shouldn't really be possible that all users are returned using this code if you have this set up correctly.  This will return only those users with the `section_id` for the single `$section` that you have pulled from the database.

Comment: @Watercayman seems like he wants all users from a Section (identified by an ID) without providing an ID.  #facepalm

Comment: @Watercayman I want just users have the same id from section_id : like this section_id = id get all users ):

Comment: OK.  That's good - then what I've written is exactly the right answer.  This will give you `section_id = id` based on the relationship.

Comment: thank you now I got it :) can you explain these $section = Section::with('users')->first();
$usersForThisSection = $section->users;

Comment: Glad you got it.  The first code is to get the section (you can get the first one in the db, or use `->find($section_id)` instead of `->first()` if you are looking for a specific section).  You are also eager loading the users along with the **section** model.  This will *only load the users who are attached to that section, because Laravel is looking at the `section_id` on the users to pull them -- this is what the relationship is doing behind the scenes.*  Then, in the second code, you are just pulling the *already-loaded* users from the `$section` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a One to Many relationship you can say things like: `$user->section` to return the section a user belongs to...and `$section->users` to get a collection of all the users in a section -- the getAllUsers() is redundant in this case.

Make sure your User and Section models contain these methods.  Sounds like your migration was setup properly if you have a section_id column on your users table.

More info on one-to-many here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```
// app/User.php

class User extends Model
{
  public function section() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
  }
}
```

```
// app/Section.php

class Section extends Model
{
  public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
}
```

Test out your relationships in `php artisan tinker` like so...

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->section
```

```
$section = Section::find(1);
$section->users
```

Comment: I dont want to use id !

Comment: Which ID? Section or User ID? If you want to load resources from the DB you're going to need a unique identifier.  If you want to use a column not named ID on either side of it, then refer to the doc and provide your own keys.

Comment: no no I just  want users have the same id from section_id : like this section_id = id get all users ):

Comment: Then my above solution is what you want, try it.

Answer (score 0):

you need a unique identifier to receive section_id's users. receive it from url(get) or ajax(post) . if you worry about users access then use "auth"